# gradle build image using a different version than the one mentioned in docker file

Tags: java, docker

I have java 13 installed on my machine and I have a project where I mentioned java 11 in the Dockerfile, so what should happen here is that when I build the docker image it should be built on top of java 11.
but surprisingly I get this error when running the container `com/example/Application has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime`.
The Dockerfile:

```
FROM  openjdk:11.0.2-jdk

# Unpack distribution tar
ADD /distributions/application.tar /

RUN mkdir /src
RUN mkdir /src/main
RUN mkdir /src/main/resources
RUN mkdir /src/main/resources/ssl
ADD ./main/resources/ssl/keystore.p12 /src/main/resources/ssl/keystore.p12

# create JAR with unversioned name
RUN cp /application/lib/application-*.jar /application/lib/application.jar

ENTRYPOINT java -jar /application/lib/application.jar
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile? Also why don't you simply use java11 for building or java13 in your docker container?

Comment: @akortex, yes I can use java 11 but that's the power of docker it's an isolated zone where you can build your app with the version and packages that suits you right? I have added the dockerfile as you asked

Comment: Well it depends on your use case. What you seem to do is build the application outside of Docker using a X Java version, then attempt to dockerize your app using a Y Java version. This combination does not guarantee isolation. What you need to do in order to attain this would be to build the application during the dockerization of your app. However this means that you may run to issues further down the line, since you will be developing for version 13 and targeting version 11.

Comment: @akortex oh I see, you're right thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something similar to this:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:16.0.2_7-jdk-centos7 AS builder
VOLUME /tmp
COPY . .
WORKDIR /
RUN ./gradlew assemble

FROM eclipse-temurin:16.0.2_7-jdk-centos7

WORKDIR /
COPY --from=builder build/libs build/libs
RUN ls -lah

RUN jar -xvf build/libs/*.jar
COPY build/libs/BOOT-INF/lib app/lib
COPY build/libs/META-INF/ app/META-INF
COPY build/libs/BOOT-INF/classes app/
RUN rm -rf build/libs

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "app:app/lib/*", "com.example.springtest.SpringTestApplication"]
```

which effectively is a multi stage docker file that builds the image internally at the docker container. This means that your choice of Java version for building is locked down and does not get affected by what you run on your local machine. However, as mentioned before there are a few caveats here:

1. Developing against a newer Java version and then attempting to target an older one can lead to compatibility issues.
2. Always re-building the project in order to produce a Docker image can affect performance negatively (image what would happen if you were to run this at a CI level).

Thus based on all the above, I would suggest to align your development environment with what you are targeting as a deployment. This is turn would allow you to build the application locally and then simply proceed into copying the necessary artifacts/assets into the created container.